# Entity Framework Core: FK with Different DataType than PK

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

**Runtime**: netcoreapp2.0

**ASP.Net Core**: 2.0.1

**EF Core**: 2.0.1

**Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer**: 2.0.1

So, I'm working on an old database that is being used by lots of services and the original creators defined the PK of one table as short and a FK to that table as an int. Is it at all possible for me to handle this case?

**Note: it is not feasible to change the column type at this time.**

Consider the two classes:

```
public class Database {
  public short DatabaseId { get; set; }
  public Database { get; set; }
}

public class Client {
  public int ClientId { get; set; }
  public int DatabaseId { get; set; }
  public Database Database { get; set; }
}
```

My first attempt:

```
public int DatabaseId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("DatabaseId")] public Database Database { get; set; }
```

throws

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The relationship from 'Client.Database' to 'Database.Client' with foreign key properties {'DatabaseId' : int} cannot target the primary key {'DatabaseId' : short} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this relationship.
```

Using the fluent API now:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Client>(table => {    
    table.HasOne(p => p.Database)
        .WithOne(i => i.Client)
        .HasForeignKey<Client>(c => c.DatabaseId)
        .HasPrincipalKey<Database>(d => d.DatabaseID);
});
```

Attempting to define a shadow property failed

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Client>(table => {
    table.Property<int>("DatabaseId");

    table.HasOne(p => p.Database)
        .WithOne(i => i.Client)
        .HasForeignKey("DatabaseId")
        .HasPrincipalKey<Database>(d => d.DatabaseId);
});
```

throws

```
System.InvalidOperationException: You are configuring a relationship between 'Client' and 'Database' but have specified a foreign key on 'DatabaseId'. The foreign key must be defined on a type that is part of the relationship.
```

Okay, so no shadow properties this time:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Client>(table => {

    table.HasOne(p => p.Database)
        .WithOne(i => i.Client)
        .HasForeignKey<Client>(c => c.DatabaseId)
        .HasPrincipalKey<Database>(d => d.SQLDatabaseID);
});
```

throws

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The types of the properties specified for the foreign key {'DatabaseId'} on entity type 'Client' do not match the types of the properties in the principal key {'DatabaseID'} on entity type 'Database'.
```

So, then I tried just changing the entity type and maybe EF will be able to map int to int16.

```
public class Client {
  public int ClientId { get; set; }
  public short DatabaseId { get; set; } // <-- now a short
  public Database Database { get; set; }
}
```

throws

```
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception occurred while reading a database value for property 'Client.DatabaseId'. The expected type was 'System.Int16' but the actual value was of type 'System.Int32'. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Int16'.
```

I'm starting to get the feeling this is not possible.

Comment: So... what would happen if you had a row with id `short.MaxValue + 1`? How would EF map that to `short`? How would you store the value on the database? Can you change the database?

Comment: Damn thats a dousy not sure what they where thinking when making an Id a short. But If its impossible to change the schema you can convert your Identifiers to ToString() while executing linq queries(dirty un-maintainable fix). You can also explicitly convert by casting ex Convert.ToInt16(int.MaxValue);

Comment: I am still trying to figure why in gods name you would use a SHORT

Comment: The problem isn't just executing simple queries which would be fine...The problem occurs when trying to follow the navigation properties e.g. _databases.Include(d => d.Client)
EF can't follow the navigation property

Comment: I have duplicated your attempt reference my comment on the answer below...

Comment: This is currently a limitation of EF and they are planning on supporting it with Value Converters (https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11112#event-1501968692). However, there is a known issue preventing it and should be fixed in 2.1 github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11117. I will update with an answer once the ValueConverters issue is fixed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In EF Core 2.1 you can use value conversions, i.e.

```
entityBuilder.Property(c => c.Id).HasConversion<string>();
```

where the generic string is the database type and the destination is the model type. You can read further on https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions

Answer (score 2):

You can bypass error generated by entity framework by using the following code to define your foreign key

```
[Column(TypeName = "int")]
public short DatabaseId { get; set; }
```

but once you run migrations you will get this error and this is generated by sql server.

> Column 'Databases.DatabaseId' is not the same data type as referencing column 'Clients.DatabaseId' in foreign key 'FK_Clients_Databases_DatabaseId'.

And this makes perfect sense. What you are trying to achieve is not physically possible as SQL server requires foreign key to be same type otherwise you cannot build foreign key relationship.

Comment: I'm not concerned about migrations since the application I'm writing does not own the database. However, this still does not work and throws: System.InvalidOperationException: An exception occurred while reading a database value for property 'Client.DatabaseId'. The expected type was 'System.Int16' but the actual value was of type 'System.Int32'. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Int16'. I also tried going the other way and defining it as an int

Comment: @jaredcnance it doesn't have anything to do with migrations it has everything to do with design.  Your attempting to fit a Square Peg in a round HOLE.  INT != SHORT in SQL SERVER, SHORT = SMALLINT, SMALLINT != INT in Sql Server. Truncation! EF is smart enough to know this... hence the error, and why ef core is rolling around on floor twitching..

Comment: My comment about migrations was in response to the answer. I am aware that migrations is not the issue. I'm searching for a workaround to this problem because I cannot feasibly alter the database. Other applications depend on the current datatypes and would break if I altered the database. If this absolutely cannot be done, then fine I'll have to use Dapper or not use the navigation properties. My question is whether or not a workaround exists in EF Core.

Comment: @jaredcnance you cannot do that physically, even Dapper will not work. and the end you will get exception `foreign key is not of same type` this is only possible if you remove the relation between your tables and handle all foreign keys manually. If you remove the relation then joins will not work in normal way (you will also lose the navigation properties)